# netcdf in python3.x not working correclty for some functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, netcdf

I noticed that the netcdf function variables.keys() for python3 is not working as expected. Instead of returning a list of keys (dictionary) as it does when using python2 this returns the whole block of information as it would have done when calling the function without parenthesis.
This is not the only function that behaves in this way in python3. My understanding is that netcdf4 libraries have been ported to py3.

The following is the expected output from the function:

```
In [5]: nc.variables.keys()
Out[5]: 
[u'area',
 u'lat',
 u'lat_bnds',
 u'lon',
 u'lon_bnds',
 u'msk_rgn',
 u'plev',
 u'pr',
 u'tas',
 u'time',
 u'time_bnds',
 u'ua']
```

And this is what is produced instead:

```
In [15]: nc.variables.keys()
Out[15]: 
KeysView(OrderedDict([('area', <class 'netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 area(lat, lon)
    long_name: Surface area
    units: meter2
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (128, 256)
filling off
), ('lat', <class 'netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 lat(lat)
    long_name: latitude
    units: degrees_north
    axis: Y
    standard_name: latitude
    bounds: lat_bnds
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (128,)
filling off
), ('lat_bnds', <class 'netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 lat_bnds(lat, bnds)
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (128, 2)
filling off
), ('lon', <class 'netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 lon(lon)
    long_name: longitude
    units: degrees_east
    axis: X
    standard_name: longitude
    bounds: lon_bnds
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (256,)
filling off
), ('lon_bnds', <class 'netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 lon_bnds(lon, bnds)
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (256, 2)
filling off
), ('msk_rgn', <class 'netCDF4.Variable'>
int32 msk_rgn(lat, lon)
    long_name: Mask region
    units: bool
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (128, 256)
filling off
), ('plev', <class 'netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 plev(plev)
    long_name: pressure
    units: Pa
    standard_name: air_pressure
    positive: down
    axis: Z
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (17,)
filling off
), ('pr', <class 'netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 pr(time, lat, lon)
    comment: Created using NCL code CCSM_atmm_2cf.ncl on
 machine eagle163s
    missing_value: 1e+20
    _FillValue: 1e+20
    cell_methods: time: mean (interval: 1 month)
    history: (PRECC+PRECL)*r[h2o]
    original_units: m-1 s-1
    original_name: PRECC, PRECL
    standard_name: precipitation_flux
    units: kg m-2 s-1
    long_name: precipitation_flux
    cell_method: time: mean
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (1, 128, 256)
filling off
), ('tas', <class 'netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 tas(time, lat, lon)
    comment: Created using NCL code CCSM_atmm_2cf.ncl on
 machine eagle163s
    missing_value: 1e+20
    _FillValue: 1e+20
    cell_methods: time: mean (interval: 1 month)
    history: Added height coordinate
    coordinates: height
    original_units: K
    original_name: TREFHT
    standard_name: air_temperature
    units: K
    long_name: air_temperature
    cell_method: time: mean
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (1, 128, 256)
filling off
), ('time', <class 'netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 time(time)
    calendar: noleap
    standard_name: time
    axis: T
    units: days since 0000-1-1
    bounds: time_bnds
    long_name: time
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (1,)
filling off
), ('time_bnds', <class 'netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 time_bnds(time, bnds)
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (1, 2)
filling off
), ('ua', <class 'netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 ua(time, plev, lat, lon)
    comment: Created using NCL code CCSM_atmm_2cf.ncl on
 machine eagle163s
    missing_value: 1e+20
    cell_methods: time: mean (interval: 1 month)
    long_name: eastward_wind
    history: Interpolated U with NCL 'vinth2p_ecmwf'
    units: m s-1
    original_units: m s-1
    original_name: U
    standard_name: eastward_wind
    _FillValue: 1e+20
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (1, 17, 128, 256)
filling off
)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, but a consequence of changes to dictionaries, specifically `OrderedDict` in this case, in Python 3.x. In Python 3.x, the `keys()` method no longer returns a list of the keys, but rather an iterator object. The output you see is just the iterator object (`KeysView`) and its referencing the original dictionary, which is then showing its representation.

If you need a list of the keys, you need to specifically ask: `list(nc.variables.keys())`.